# How does MapReduce processing work with Local File System?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

How does MapReduce processing work if the inputs/output are from local file system?

Does MapReduce job execution happen asynchronously across the Hadoop cluster?
If yes, how does that happen?

In which usecase, do we actually need to use this approach?

Comment: Use what approach? Reading from local filesystem only makes sense if you are testing a small file set. In which case, Hadoop is not really necessary

Comment: @cricket_007 In which usecase, do we actually need to use this approach "Hadoop MapReduce jobs with Local File System on Cluster"?

Comment: If you have a cluster, you would never use the local filesystem. Put your data in HDFS and then process it

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. MapReduce Works even same in local system (mapper->reducer)

   (only its  matter of efficiency as it will be less efficient in local system rather than  cluster).
2. Yes,MapReduce job execution happen asynchronously across the Hadoop cluster(it depends on what kind of scheduler you are using in your mapreduce program)

   click [for more about scheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html)
3. In most of the case this used for testing purpose (running mapreduce program in local system).

Comment: Thanks Andani. I will look at them all.